# Is it possible to Assign IP address to each core of Graphics Card or GPU?

Tags: networking, graphics-card, cpu, gpu

I was wondering when I had a chance to look at some applications which are multi-core. They utilize all the cores of the CPU effectively by assigning IP addresses with port.

I had a question in my mind, whether is it possible to use GPU cores in the similar manner? Can I assign IP and port to all the cores of GPU and then use them as multi core in the application?

Kindly, suggest me your views.

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking. CPU cores aren't assigned IP addresses. They have no network interface. Same goes for GPU cores.

Comment: @n8te Had you ever encountered with the Agent farm in MT5? There you will see that the cores of the system are assigned with the IP of the system and have different ports.

Comment: @n8te Do you think this will help me? https://www.usenix.org/node/186166

Comment: Which still means you're addressing the system and not the cores.

Comment: Some people had flagged me as  unclear what you're asking. I would like to tell you that, if I was unclear then how the person has answered my question? Please take a note before flagging.

Comment: @jaffer Wilson, that person didn't actually answer the question. And it's very unclear what you are trying to ask, or do. I would think trying to label and access CPU/GPU cores through the TCP/IP stack would NOT be very effective or efficient compared to traditional hardware I/O.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, it's theoretically possible to do that. But I don't know of any problem it would solve, so there wouldn't be much point. One major reason why is that GPUs have many  more cores and a single one of them isn't particularly useful, so dividing a task over a network at GPU core granularity makes very little sense. There's a reason we don't schedule bicycles the same way we schedule airplanes.

Comment: Is it possible to assign system level port to all the GPU cores?

Comment: @JafferWilson You can do it precisely the same way MT5 does it, but it would make no sense to do so. You can do it with one process or more than one process. You simply listen to various ports and depending on which port you received a job on, dispatch it to the appropriate GPU core. But you'd be dispatching bicycles the way we dispatch airplanes -- the overhead would kill any efficiency.

Comment: Great to hear from you David. I am working on some deep learning algorithm. For that purpose I am in a dense need of cores which GPU can give me. I am having Titan Xp which has given me great results in my previous experiments. Hence, wanting to try it  with MT5 this time. Can you help me in assigning the ports to the GPU cores, please? My humble request.

Comment: Can you please tell me how I can get the core address of the GPU device? say, my CPU core number 0 is at port number 3000 and is till 3007. Is there something similar for the GPU device too? Please let me know. Your help will be appreciated and updated... :)

Comment: There is nothing similar until you make something similar.